# How to create an ng-repeat with data from db?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create an `ng-repeat` that shows a list of "organizations".

Basically, users can create projects in different organizations (Org A, Org B, Org C, etc) and I want to display all the organizations that a user has a project on, with a list.

Each user has a var associated called `active_projects` that saves all the Organizations they got a project and the project ID.
Example: `{"ORG A":5087,"ORG B":5025}`.

And each organization has `name` var that saves the name I want to display. Example: `ORG A`.

I have an example that does something similar, but with clusters:

```
<li ng-repeat="cluster in administrableClusterContainer.administrableClusters">
  <a href="{{ cluster.impersonateUrl }}">{{ cluster.name }}</a>
</li>
```

My doubt is how to fill the `ng-repeat` for the new case.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties

Comment: use two `ng-repeat`, one for array of objects, the other one for `(key, value)` pair of each object. Then display it as `{{key}}` `{{value}}` in your context